# mongo-scala-driver :how to add connection pool size in MOngoClient Settings

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

i am new to mongo scala driver i am trying to add connection pool size when initiating a mongo instance 
i am doing it something like this

```
  val settings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
    .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(ConnectionPoolSettings.Builder.maxSize(100))
    .applyToClusterSettings(b => b.hosts(List(new ServerAddress("localhost")).asJava).description("Local Server"))
    .build()

  val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient(settings)
```

value maxSize is not a member of object com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings.Builder
[error]     .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(ConnectionPoolSettings.Builder.maxSize(100))

what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a small typo on your code

**ConnectionPoolSettings.Builder.maxSize(100)**

should be

**ConnectionPoolSettings.builder().maxSize(100)**

The code with the Block would look like this:

```
val settings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
  .applyToConnectionPoolSettings((t: ConnectionPoolSettings.Builder) => t.applySettings(ConnectionPoolSettings.builder().maxSize(100).build()))
  .applyToClusterSettings(b => b.hosts(List(new ServerAddress("localhost")).asJava).description("Local Server"))
  .build()
```